# Configuring updates on startup fails

Tags: windows-7, boot, windows-update

Just recently every time I try to start up Windows 7 I get a 'Windows is configuring updates 0%' message - for about 10 minutes then all of a sudden I get a failure error and Windows is reverting any changes.

This has been going on a continuous rate. I checked the update history and theres a number of failed updates - an example of one is as below:

```
Update for Windows 7 for x64-based Systems (KB2515325)

Installation date: ‎4/‎29/‎2011 6:34 PM

Installation status: Failed

Error details: Code 800705B4

Update type: Recommended

This is a reliability update. This update resolves some performance and reliability issues in Windows. By applying this update, you can achieve better performance and responsiveness in various scenarios. For more information please see the Knowledge Base article. After you install this item, you may have to restart your computer.
```

How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: oh, irony, `This is a reliability update`.

Answer (score 1):

You could check the Windows Event Log to figure out why the upgrade is failing.

You could also run Windows Update (from the Control Panel) and roll that particular update back.

Answer (score 1):

Try deleting the "pending.xml" file at this location, reboot, hopefully that configuring message will not run.

```
C:\Windows\winsxs\pending.xml
```

.

Then try another Windows update, see what updates it offers.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and fixed the issue by installing the updates individually.

1. Click Start > All Programs > Windows Updates
2. Select the Windows Update (it should say 4 Important Updates) or some number there (it will vary)
3. Select that link and de-select all but 1 update (install it only)
4. Reboot if necessary - if no reboot is needed then do the next one. Reboot if it asks for it.
5. Do this until all updates are installed.

Answer (score 1):

Please read this post, maybe it helps: [Fix: Failure configuring windows updates reverting changes (Windows 7)](http://www.gotechtips.net/2012/08/fix-failure-configuring-windows-updates.html)

> - Restart your PC/laptop
> - Keep tapping F8 as soon as see the initialization screen
> - Choose Safemode
> - Once Safemode is fully loaded, hit Start, type `cmd`
> - Right click on cmd and chose Run as Administrator
> - On the Command Prompt screen type `sfc /scannow`
> - When it's done, type `chkdsk /f/r`
> - Restart the PC/laptop and boot to Windows as normal

Answer (score 0):

Try : control panel / System and security / Troubleshoot common computer problems (action center) / Fix problems with Windows Update (System and security)

Answer (score 0):

What I did was I manually installed the update via control panel then restart.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem as well.
Solved it by going back to a previous restore point just before the updates were trying to install, and then re-installing manually via control panel. Just had to reboot once for all the updates.
Hope this works for you, too!

Answer (score 0):

One other alternative is to try using the [Microsoft Baseline Security Analyzer 2.2](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/security/cc184923) which will tell you which updates your machine needs and to offer download links to the individual patch files. Sometimes Windows Update gets itself into a mess and it can be fixed by individually downloading and installing the necessary updates.